# How to find the next occurrence of an expression in the Chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, find, google-chrome-devtools

The Chrome debugger tells me that it found for example 42 occurrences of a given expression.
How on earth do I jump to the next occurrence?

Comment: OK, just found it: simply press "Enter" to jump to the next occurrence. Why is it not the standard F3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in the Search Box, hit Enter repeatedly to move to the next match

In windows at least :-

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> is Goto Line

Comment: Shift + Enter to go reverse

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search in the chrome developer tools. Enter and <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will go to the next match, and <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will go to the previous one.

Note: On Mac, <kbd>C</kbd> == <kbd>Command</kbd>. On Windows/Linux, <kbd>C</kbd> == <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: The documentation says C-g will go to the next match, but in my experience on Windows it invokes 'go to line...'.

Comment: Actually, from your profile it looks like you might be in a position to fix this discrepancy between documentation and implementation http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/shortcuts.html

Comment: FWIW, in the script debugger this isn't how it works at all.  You have to press "enter" repeatedly to advance to the next match.

Answer (score 0):

Control + Shift + F opens a super search box with which you can find a string across all of the scripts. This can help when you have a lot of inline scripts for a page.